# CGImageRef Memory leak after release and autoreleasepool

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, quartz-core

Im trying to implement show image from local content but for some reason memory Would not get freed.

```
@autoreleasepool {
  ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
  CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
  UIImage *largeimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale orientation:(UIImageOrientation)rep.orientation];
  CFRelease(iref);
  self.imageView.image = largeimage;
  largeimage = nil;
 }
```

As suggested ,i am used

```
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

but still  i am got an memory leak. After that i am wrap code with an

```
@autoreleasepool {}
```

block but that also not solve my problem.
What chould I do ?

Comment: You should not be calling `CFRelease` on `iref`.

Comment: How have you determine you have a memory leak?

Comment: i am using instruments with leaks option.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is when you assign the image to your image view. Can you try resizing the image before assigning it to image view?

Use this method

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)sourceImage toSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [sourceImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: There is slightly difference in memory, but still memory issue is there.